# Read external assets continously into photoshop (or other program?)

Tags: templates, assets, photoshop, adobe-indesign

I want to create some banner templates with external assets.

```
e.g.
template.psd
assets/
  file.png
  file2.png
```

The catch is when I overwrite file.png with another image I want photoshop to display that new image instead of loading the old one.

This has to be done automatically. Does somebody have an idea or know a program where I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention the version of Photoshop you are using, but from the 2014, I think, there is a Linked Smart Objects feature where you can link to external files. These will auto-update when the host PSD file is open and you save it. Unfortunately, you have to update manually if the file was closed when changes were made to the external files.

On a mac you can use applescript attached to a folder to update the main PSD file on any changes.

You tagged your post with InDesign tag as well. In Indesign you link placed images to the external files. Any changes on the image files will propagate to the main InDesign file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out tomorrow then I'll accept your answer :)